# Heavy Load crashes user started processes on Linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a old laptop, with a old Pentium dual core at (I think) 2.3 ghz, running Linux mint 17.3 --- Mate

When the laptop gets a heavy load such as video decoding it can just freeze for a few seconds but afterwards some and most often randomly, processes that I started manually, not the ones on my user started by the system such as the desktop, crash.
It seems though as if they are shut down correctly, as file writing processes always finish their work and never just break off.

I can't list any processes that crash as it is random, but most common non graphics processes stop. Things such as Firefox tend to end less.

Answer (score 1):

What you're likely encountering is the [OOM killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer), which is part of the normal Linux memory management strategy. When the memory manager (Linux kernel) can no longer provide memory to userland and kernel processes, the OOM killer has an algorithm that selects one or more processes based on a "badness" value it calculates for each one.

From a user perspective, this can seem like a "random" (non-deterministic) crashing of programs, including foreground and background applications like a typical desktop environment.

Video decoding is very CPU intensive, but what triggers the OOM killer are the *memory* requirements. Do you have any options available to you to decrease the memory usage of the video decoder, perhaps by using smaller buffers? Other than that, your only (practical) defense is to increase the amount of available memory, which can mean physically upgrading the memory, or preemptively shutting down other memory-hungry processes on your system.

### Tracking down memory-hungry processes

You can track down memory-hungry processes with the `top -o %MEM` command. If Linux Mint's `top` doesn't support the `-o %MEM` syntax, just run `top` by itself and use the <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> keys to change the sort field.

The nice side-effect of this technique is that you can also see how much memory and swap space are available, in the first few lines of the `top` screen:

```
top - 14:13:43 up 5 days,  4:00,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.02, 0.05
Tasks: 168 total,   2 running, 166 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.0 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2049988 total,  1231344 used,   818644 free,   358072 buffers
KiB Swap:  2095100 total,   217588 used,  1877512 free.   450268 cached Mem
```

#### Killing processes yourself

You can then use this information to preemptively kill (exit) any unneeded processes using a lot of memory, so the OOM killer hopefully won't kill something important. Two methods:

1. Type `kill 12345` in another terminal (where `12345` is the "PID" as displayed by `top`), or
2. In `top`, pressing <kbd>k</kbd>, enter the PID when prompted, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

It should go without saying, but be careful when killing processes. Exiting an application normally with its Quit command is usually preferable, so you are sure to not lose any unsaved work.